# Maximize expected return

Tags: optimization

making a practice exam I had to make the following problem which I couldn't solve unfortunately...

---

**Problem**

In the springtime, a student has $N$ days to find a summer job for one month. Each day, the student is offered a job with total salary drawn from a exponential distribution with mean $R > 0$. The offers are independent. The costs of applying for jobs is $c < R$; the student pays these costs each time he rejects an offer. The offer on day $N$ is accepted in all cases. He cannot revisit a rejected offer. When should the student accept an offer?

---

I hope someone can help me..

Answer (score 2):

The last day's offer has expected pay $R$.

Let's suppose the expected value if you start the $k$th day is $R_k$, so  $R_N=R$.

Therefore the $k-1$th day's offer should be accepted if and only if its offer is greater than $R_k-c$, since you could instead choose to pay $c$ and then take your chance on the $k$th day.

If you start the $k-1$th day, the probability of accepting that day's offer is $\exp\left(-\frac{R_k-c}{R}\right)$ and conditioned on accepting it then (using memorylessness) the expected pay is $R+R_k-c$. So the expected position if you reach the $k-1$th day is  $R_{k-1}=(R+R_k-c)\exp\left(-\frac{R_k-c}{R}\right) + (R_k-c)\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{R_k-c}{R}\right)\right)$, i.e. $R_{k-1}= R\exp\left(-\frac{R_k-c}{R}\right) +R_k -c$.

Comment: @Thank you, could you please explain how I can solve the recursive formula you showed me?

Comment: I would do it numerically

Comment: But I have to solve it for general $N$

Comment: use some sofware,like matlab and  choose different $N$,and compare results

Comment: This method works for general $N$, just not in a closed form.  The answer is "accept the $k−1$th day's offer if and only if its offer is greater than $R_k−c$; if you reach the last day, accept that offer".

Comment: @Henry I see what you mean, but you cannot revisit the $k-1$th offer if you know the $k$th offer, am I right?

Comment: @Sjoerd That is correct.  But the values of $R_k$ do not depend on the actual offers. They are just numbers depending on $R$ and $c$ and can all be calculated in advance of the whole process.  You then accept an offer on a particular day if it is high enough, and go on to the next day if not.

Answer (score 1):

we know that  exponential distribution has  following form
    [exponential](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/5/0/450b84da3274134a4f8280d8b46067b9.png/exponential)

now if student reject  offers he  paid  $c$ right?so if he  rejected $x$ times,it means cost $x*c$ is it right?so our problem is that we  have to determine number of days he should reject so that  cost $x*c$  should be minimum as well  as salary must be maxsimum,so i think we have to find  number of $x$ so that cost must be minimum and  salary maximum,we may use Lagrangian multiplier or another method ,

Comment: I don't see what you mean here, I also don't understand the answer, can you please be more specific?

Comment: so your salary is represented by  exponential distribution right?imagine that you have rejected  job offering $x$ times,cos is  $x*c$ right? so now what does mean cost minimum?clearly you can reject  on first time,but because for different  $x$,salary is different,try to find $x$ which maximize  salary and minimize cost,is it clear?

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean but the way on how to find this maximum is not clear to me..

Comment: you have to maximize  salary-cost